# SQL Show dates without transactions as value = 0

Tags: sql, date

I'm doing a weight reporting and I have a problem. I use this query to know the enters of weight in our warehouse, but when there are no transactions in a date this date doesn't appears in the results.

```
SELECT  erp.MKPF.BUDAT AS Data,  
Sum( erp.MSEG.MENGE * erp.MARM.BRGEW ) as pes 

From erp.MKPF  
INNER Join erp.MSEG on erp.MKPF.MANDT = erp.MSEG.MANDT and erp.MKPF.MBLNR = erp.MSEG.MBLNR  
INNER Join erp.MARM on erp.MSEG.MANDT = erp.MARM.MANDT and erp.MSEG.MATNR = erp.MARM.MATNR And erp.MSEG.MEINS = erp.MARM.MEINH  
INNER JOIN erp.MARA on erp.MSEG.MANDT = erp.MARA.MANDT and erp.MSEG.MATNR = erp.MARA.MATNR

WHERE  erp.MKPF.MANDT = '100'  
and erp.MKPF.BUDAT >= '20120720' 
and erp.MKPF.BUDAT <= CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112) -1 
and erp.MSEG.LGORT in ('1001','1069') 
and erp.MSEG.BWART In ('101','102','311','312') 
and erp.MSEG.WERKS = '1001' 
and erp.MARA.MTART in ('Z001','Z010','Z002','Z02E') 

GROUP BY erp.MKPF.BUDAT*
```

Now the results are like this:

```
Data        PES
20120720    9999999.9999
20120721    9999999.8888
20120723    9999999.7777
```

And i need this

```
Data        PES
20120720    9999999.9999
20120721    9999999.8888
20120722    0
20120723    999999.7777
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: I know of no easy way to modify your query to get the dataset you want. How is the data finally presented to the user? This might be a better/easier place to add display logic to fill the empty dates with 0 values.

Comment: If you construct auxiliary date table and left join MKPF to it on budat, you will get missing dates. The filtering condition should be applied on date table.

Comment: Ignore my deleted answer - completely misread the question. Agree with Nikola here, though this should give you some ideas. http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/09/10/group-by-month-sql.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a table or a view to generate the date range of interest and let this drive the query. Then you outer join your results to this view. This can be done dynamically in the query. For example, in Oracle, you can use "connect by" to generate a series:

```
create table my_summary(the_day date, pes number);
insert into my_summary values(to_date('20120720', 'yyyymmdd'),  9999999.9999);
insert into my_summary values(to_date('20120721', 'yyyymmdd'),  9999999.8888);
insert into my_summary values(to_date('20120723', 'yyyymmdd'),  9999999.7777);

SELECT d.the_day, NVL(s.pes, 0) AS pes
  FROM ( SELECT to_date('20120720', 'yyyymmdd') + level -1 AS the_day
           FROM dual CONNECT BY level <= 4) d
       LEFT OUTER JOIN my_summary s ON (d.the_day = s.the_day)
  ORDER BY 1

THE_DAY   PES
--------- ---
20-JUL-12 9999999.9999 
21-JUL-12 9999999.8888 
22-JUL-12   0 
23-JUL-12 9999999.7777
```

Other rdbms have other methods to generate a series. This will require you to know the start date you want, and the number of records (in the example above 20120720 and 4).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all, finally I did this and it works

```
    SELECT 
    c.BUDAT AS DATA, 
    CASE When SAP.pes Is Null then '0'
    ELSE SAP.pes
    END
From
    erp.YSD_CALENDAR as c LEFT JOIN

    (SELECT 
    erp.MKPF.BUDAT,
    Sum(
    erp.MSEG.MENGE
     * erp.MARM.BRGEW ) as pes
     FROM
     erp.MKPF 

INNER Join erp.MSEG on erp.MKPF.MANDT = erp.MSEG.MANDT and erp.MKPF.MBLNR = erp.MSEG.MBLNR  

INNER Join erp.MARM on erp.MSEG.MANDT = erp.MARM.MANDT and erp.MSEG.MATNR = erp.MARM.MATNR And erp.MSEG.MEINS = erp.MARM.MEINH 

INNER JOIN erp.MARA on erp.MSEG.MANDT = erp.MARA.MANDT and erp.MSEG.MATNR = erp.MARA.MATNR 

WHERE 
    erp.MKPF.MANDT = '100' 
and erp.MKPF.BUDAT >= '20120720'
and erp.MSEG.LGORT in ('1001','1069')
and erp.MSEG.BWART In ('101','102','311','312')
and erp.MSEG.WERKS = '1001'
and erp.MARA.MTART in ('Z001','Z010','Z002','Z02E')
and erp.MSEG.SHKZG = 'S'
GROUP BY erp.MKPF.BUDAT
) SAP ON SAP.BUDAT = c.BUDAT 

WHERE 
c.BUDAT >= '20120720'
and c.BUDAT <=  CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)

GROUP BY c.BUDAT, SAP.pes
ORDER BY c.BUDAT
```